# R data.frame - Swapping columns and rows

Tags: r, statistics

As part of a Statistics project, I am required to find and compare two estimates of the parameter of an exponential distribution. I have obtained two vectors, each containing the estimates:

```
lambda <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
direct_estimates <- c({ten estimates by method 1})
mle_estimates <- c({ten estimates by method 2})
```

Then I tried to put them into a data.frame as follows
[See Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujHVZ.png) and as you can see, rather than put the estimates into columns alongside the respective parameter, it puts all 20 of them along the rows. I have tried using the transpose function `t()` to fix this but I've just made a bigger mess of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: Is it possible the estimates are actually lists, or some other data structure that you have mistakenly called a “vector”?

Comment: Potentially, my knowledge of R is bad at best. Do lists behave differently to vectors in data frames?

Comment: Yes, potentially. The other possibility is that they are matrices. You can check by running `str()` on the object and sharing the results in your question. Also, putting the output from `dput()` would allow other people to actually manipulate the objects on their own.

Comment: Running str on the objects showed two of them were lists and the parameter one was a vector. Applying unlist to flatten the lists into vectors fixed the issue. Thank you for all your help! :)